# SMTPTransport sendMessage stuck on connection loss

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

i am using javamail's SMTPTransport.sendMessage method to send emails in my android app and everything works fine... but when i start sending a message and in the middle, i disable my wifi, it gets stuck. I have waited for more than 1hour now and it is still stuck; no exception is thrown... any idea how to handle this situation?

**edit:**

i have added a timeout

```
props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "3000");
props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", "3000");
```

does not seem to work ... i have simulated a connection loss and it's already 5mins now and it is still in sending state and has not timed out

**edit2:**

timeout/error(not even sure if it is a timeout) occurred after 16mins

```
06-30 18:47:27.722: I/System.out(15906): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0xdf8268: I/O error during system call, Invalid argument
```

**edit 3:**

it does not always throw an exception... i have simulated a connection loss and after 1hr, still no exception... it is in sending state..... and have not return yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of JavaMail only handles timeouts for reads, because that's all the JDK supports.  For the next JavaMail release I've added support for write timeouts.  You can experiment with it using the 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT release of JavaMail available in the maven.java.net repository.  You'll need to set the "mail.smtp.writetimeout" property.  Don't know if this will help you on Android since it's not really Java...

Comment: ok thx i will give it a try!

can you recommend a good value for smtp.timeout read timeout? i have set it to 3000 and i am getting a lot of timeout errors even when a mail is actually sent successfully (the reply from smtp gets timed out and an error is thrown)

Comment: 3 seconds is a pretty short timeout if your mail server is at all busy.  You'll probably need to experiment to find out what's best.  The timeout should be as large as your application can tolerate since it should only trigger in very rare cases.  It should not be based on how fast you **want** the mail server to be, or how fast you think it should be.

Comment: ok i have set it to 5mins as I was getting a timeout error almost everytime

Comment: can i use setDebug to an outputstream and monitor that stream via a thread? if the stream is not outputting for more than 30seconds, kill javamail send? any idea how to implement this and if this sounds possible?

Comment: You could do that, but killing the other thread means you'll never know whether the message was actually sent or not.  And of course there might be legitimate cases where it takes the server more than 30 seconds to respond. I'm not convinced this is any better than using the existing timeout mechanism.

Comment: the write timeout on javamail 1.5.0 if i am not mistaken is 15mins... it's very long and most users and i myself would think it's locked or something if i have a mail being sent without timeout for 15mins

Comment: There's no write timeouts in JavaMail 1.5.0, they will be in JavaMail 1.5.1  You can try the 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT release.  If your mail server is frequently not responding for 15 minutes, maybe you need to get a new mail server!  :-)

Comment: it's not the server taking 15mins... i have simulated a connection loss while it is sending (turning wifi off) and it takes like 15 or more mins to timeout.. that's not ideal... where can i download a version of 1.5.1? will it work on android?

Comment: The 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT is in the [java.net maven repository](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.1-SNAPSHOT/).  You'll need to set the mail.smtp.writetimeout property.  Android isn't Java so I have no idea if it will work there.